# How to print stack trace as string once by JsonLayout of log4j2

Tags: log4j2

Im using log4j2 2.13.3 ing my project.
`<JsonLayout compact="true" eventEol="true" stacktraceAsString="true"/>`
log like this:

```
    "message": "404 NOT_FOUND \"Unable to find instance for xxx\"",
    "thrown": {
        "commonElementCount": 0,
        "localizedMessage": "404 NOT_FOUND \"Unable to find instance for xxx\"",
        "message": "404 NOT_FOUND \"Unable to find instance for xxx\"",
        "name": "org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.NotFoundException",
        "suppressed": [
            {
                "commonElementCount": 0,
                "localizedMessage": "xxx\nStack trace:",
                "message": "xxx\nStack trace:",
                "name": "reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException",
                "extendedStackTrace": "stack trace"
            }
        ],
        "extendedStackTrace": "stack trace"
    },
```

`extendedStackTrace` appears twice. Is there any way to make the stack trace appear once.

like this:(copy from http://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout)

```
[
  {
    "logger":"com.foo.Bar",
    "timestamp":"1376681196470",
    "level":"INFO",
    "thread":"main",
    "message":"Message flushed with immediate flush=true"
  },
  {
    "logger":"com.foo.Bar",
    "timestamp":"1376681196471",
    "level":"ERROR",
    "thread":"main",
    "message":"Message flushed with immediate flush=true",
    "throwable":"stack trace"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log as JSON I would suggest your upgrade and use the new JsonTemplateLayout. It gives you much more control over the generated output.

For my purposes of logging to an ELK stack I prefer to use the GELF Layout with the SocketAppender to send the logs to Logstash. See [Logging in the Cloud](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/cloud.html) for more information.